# How to save the lines that exist in file b but not exist in file a to file c, use shell script?

Tags: shell

How to save the lines that exist in file **b** but not exist in file **a** to file **c**, use shell script, for example:

content in **a.txt**:

```
abc    
123     
zxc
```

content in **b.txt**

```
rty   
fgh   
abc    
zxc   
456
```

the result in file **c.txt**:

```
rty   
fgh      
456
```

I try to deal it with join, sort, grep but can't work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer for third version of question

In this version, there are space characters in the files and we want to ignore them:

```
$ grep -vwFf <(sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' a.txt2) b.txt2
rty   
fgh   
456
```

#### Answer for second version of question

```
$ grep -vxFf a.txt b.txt
rty
fgh
456
```

This returns all lines from b.txt that are not in a.txt

The meaning of the options to `grep` are:

1. Normally, grep prints lines that match.  `-v` tells grep to do the opposite and print only lines that do not match.
2. `-x` tells grep to match whole lines.
3. `-F` tells grep that we are matching fixed strings, not regular expressions.
4. `-f a.txt` tells grep to get the lines to compare against from file a.txt.

### Answer for original version of question

**Version 1**

> how to save the lines that exist in file b but not exist in file a to file c

These are the lines in file b but are not in file a:

```
$ grep -vxFf a.txt b.txt
rty
fgh
ghj
456
```

That doesn't match your sample output.

For example `rty` is a line "that exist in file b but not exist in file a."  Thus it is correct that it is in the output.

**Version 2**

Maybe what you meant was that you wanted lines in file b that were *also* in file a.  In that case:

```
$ grep -xFf a.txt b.txt
abc
zxc
```

This matches your sample output.

To save this in file c.txt:

```
grep -xFf a.txt b.txt >c.txt
```

Comment: i have correct the output sample,your method can not work well,your method just matches one line in file a

Comment: it works ,there is a space character after zxc,delete it and it works well.

Comment: @BluesMelody If your files have spaces in them, we need a different approach.  See update to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using combine from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

**lines in b that don't exist in a**

```
$ combine b not a > c
```

**lines in both b and a**

```
$ combine b and a > c
```

Comment: it work,but moreutils is not a buildin tool in my distribution,thanks anyway.